# Your opinion: MySQL-API one-to-many relationship, VueJS and JSON

Tags: mysql, json, vue.js, relationship, one-to-many

I have a question about a best practice approach regarding a one-to-many relationship using an MySQL-API, VueJS as a framework and a data-table using a JSON format.
I have a little example available here: https://codepen.io/rasenkantenstein/pen/MWYEvzK. This is a Vuetify data table which hosts information about desserts. One dessert can have many ingredients...

My problem is similar: I have a MySQL - membership table. In case of a family membership, one membership can relate to many people of the family. In a classic scheme I would have a membership table and a members table with a foreign key to the membership.
The membership table contains attributes such as a conctact adress, entry date etc. The members table contains attributes such as the name, birthdate etc. There are also transactions which also relate to the membership table among other things.

My approach is to try to hold all information in one membership table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Membership` (
  `MembershipId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MembershipType` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `MembershipMembers` json NOT NULL COMMENT 'contains a JSON String with family name, given name and birthdate',
  `MembershipZipCode` int(11) NOT NULL, --and more attributes
```

However, two tables also seem feasable. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know how to update both tables with the JS-Axios-API inside the same data-table.

I am looking for some ressources to further help my decision making, e.g. links or certain keywords or hard advice.